# Try to add Custom Functionality to a Spring Data Repository, but got UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I tried to add several methods to Spring Data Repository but i got  UnsatisfiedDependencyException

AppUserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser,Long>,    AppUserRepositoryCustom {
}
```

CustomDetailsService.java

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usernameOrEmail)
    throws UsernameNotFoundException {
AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findByUsernameOrEmail(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail)
        .orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username or email : " + usernameOrEmail)
        );

return UserPrincipal.  create(appUser);
```

}

```
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) {
AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
        () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id : " + id)
);

return UserPrincipal.create(appUser);
```

}

AppUserRepositoryCustom.java

```
public interface AppUserRepositoryCustom {
Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);
Optional<AppUser> findByUsernameOrEmail(String username, String email); 
}
```

AppUserRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class AppUserRepositoryImpl implements AppUserRepositoryCustom {
@Override
public Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email) {
    return Optional.empty();
}

@Override
public Optional<AppUser> findByUsernameOrEmail(String username, String email) {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

}

But i got UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Caused by:   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error  creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appUserRepository';

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please annotate `AppUserRepositoryCustom` with `@Repository` annotation and retry once.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I did, but same result.

Comment: did you put @Service annotation in CustomUserDetailsService.java, all your beans must be in the Spring context

Comment: yes, i did. @Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService..